# Angular event handler property change doesn't trigger listeners

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular to trigger a dropdown that, in the case of this application, loads the content of the dropdown menu before displaying it. What I am trying to achieve is to be able to add the dropdown directive to an element, but importantly, I want the dropdown to appear *after* the element, not *inside* it, because various different elements might be used to trigger this dropdown.

I have got all this working, but I feel as though it's not quite as *Angular* as I would like as it appears to require a manual `$scope.$apply()` and it seems to me that should be unnecessary if I am working with the flow of Angular. Also as this is being used to raise a hover menu, if the mouse passes over several trigger elements Angular gets upset about multiple apply calls.

A simplified version looks like this, for HTML:

```
<div ng-app="example">
    <div example-hover>
    Hover me
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following JS:

```
var app = angular.module('example', []);

angular.module("example")
             .controller("exampleHoverController", function( $scope ) {
            $scope.showHoverList = false;

            $scope.setHoverList = function(value) {
                console.log("Set hoverlist value: "+value);
                this.showHoverList=value;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
     });

angular.module("example")
             .directive("exampleHover", function( $compile ) {
       return {
           restrict: "A",
           template: '',
           controller: 'exampleHoverController',
           link: function( scope, element) {
                  element.after('<example-dropdown></example-dropdown>');
                $compile(element.parent().find('example-dropdown'))(scope);

                element.bind("mouseover", function() {
                    scope.showHoverList = true;
                  scope.setHoverList(true);
                });
                element.bind("mouseout", function() {
                    scope.showHoverList = false;
                  scope.setHoverList(false);
                });
           }
       }
     });

 angular.module("example")
                .directive("exampleDropdown", function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          template: '<div ng-show="showHoverList">I should be visible when hovered!</template>',
          controller: "exampleHoverController"
        };
     });
```

Obligatory [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/z03huraq/). Note that this is working code, my question is: How can I achieve the same thing without needing to call `$scope.$apply` when I update the controller property in the `exampleHoverController`?

I'm aware that there are simpler ways to achieve this effect if I know all my data ahead of time, but the real versions of this code are doing a lot more than this example and I need to be able to attach the hover menu to any element and then perform some background querying when displaying it, so I really need something that matches this behaviour if not this exact pattern.

Comment: You need to call $scope.$apply because the events are coming from outside the Angular execution context. Using it here is not a hack or a bad thing, this is pretty much what its there for. You should move it directly to the event callback functions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/z03huraq/32/

You can use the compile function on your exampleHover directive to:

- Remove the directive attribute (because otherwise it would get into a loop)
- and add the 2 mouse events directly into the template html

  `compile: function(){
               return {
                   pre: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){
                      element.removeAttr("example-hover")
                             .attr("ng-mouseover","mouseOver()")
                             .attr("ng-mouseout","mouseOut()");
                      $compile(element)(scope);
                   },
                   post: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){
                      element.after('<example-dropdown></example-dropdown>');
                      $compile(element.parent().find('example-dropdown'))(scope);
                   }
               }
             }`

This will allow the digest cycle to acknowledge the event's existance.